# update query returns 0 rows from .net code. Returns 1 row from SQL Developer

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I am running an Update query from a C# code. Same query updates 1 rows from Oracle SQL Developer. but, updates 0 rows from the code.

I am using :
Oracle Database 12c , .Net Framework 4.0 , Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, LDAP for Database connection

Code :

```
OracleConnection appConnection;
appConnection.ConnectionString = "User Id=XXX;Password=XXX;Data Source=XXX";
appConnection.Open();

OracleTransaction tran = appConnection.BeginTransaction();

string query = "UPDATE TEST_TABLE SET COMMENT =:comment WHERE NAME =:name"
OracleCommand cmd= con.appConnection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = query;

cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":name", OracleDbType.Varchar2));
cmd.Parameters[":name"].Value = "New Name";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":comment", OracleDbType.Varchar2));
cmd.Parameters[":comment"].Value = "New Comment";

var val = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
tran.commit()
```

ExecuteNonQuery should return a value of 1 if one rows have been updated. Right now the output is 0.

Comment: Have you verified whether or not the row is actually updated in the database?

Comment: May it be related to the fact the a command called `cmd` is set up, while a command called `cmdUpdateGen` is executed?

Comment: By the way, I think you should omit the colon `:` when setting params. (`cmd.Parameters["name"].Value = ...`)

Comment: Sorry for the error. i have corrected the `cmdUpdateGen`  to `cmd`.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger Any specific reason why colon `:` should be omitted?

Comment: @pranjalgupta: Probably it doesn't need to be omitted. I wasn't sure about that. Sometimes the colon marks parameters in the query, followed by the parameter name. When adding parameters, only the name is needed. That's how it is in Hibernate queries for instance. You can test both, it probably doesn't actually matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this funny post: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/208176/Gotcha-sharp-Using-Named-Parameters-with-Oracl

It required to turn on named parameters.

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, con.appConnection) 
{ 
  CommandType = CommandType.Text, 
  BindByName = true 
};
```

Otherwise, parameters are bound by position. Because you have a different position of the parameters in the query than you add it to the command, it didn't work.

Comment: Thank you! Was stuck for 2 days.